# Black screen after using CD for Ubuntu 12.04 on Sony VAIO VGN FE780G

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, cd

I have a Sony VAIO VGN FE780G with 2GB RAM and an Intel graphics card.

First, I put my installation CD in and went installing just an Ubuntu single boot, no Windows. Then after I entered my name and password, the screen went black.

I rebooted my laptop and I got into the desktop, but I couldn't do anything, so I've decided to reinstall Ubuntu and now nothing runs. The first screen after I put in the CD goes to a black screen.  At some point it did show some commands running, but then it stopped.

How can I get Ubuntu 12.04 running on my machine?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same laptop. I had to use Ubuntu Alternate 12.04.3 LTS 32bit.
The regular 12.04 would load and then hang. The Alternate install works great for me.

http://releases.ubuntu.com

ubuntu-12.04.3-alternate-i386.iso